# Selenium web driver can't open browser on Heroku

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, heroku, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an Node.js app with a Python script that uses Selenium webdriver.
When I ran it locally everything is working as expected. When deployed to Heroku the web browser fail to open from app.

Here is my code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\path\\to drivers\\geckodriver.exe')
browser.minimize_window()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

The browser console error:

> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Update:
Based on suggestion from Chris I updated the code to:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

and added google-chrome buildpack.
[image]

But still can't open browser when running web version.
Heroku log mentions PATH. But drivers are in PATH. everything works locally.
Obviously, I am missing something.

> 2019-08-07T11:27:54.690913+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This SO answer suggests reading the logs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382995/500-internal-server-error-heroku

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\path\\to drivers\\geckodriver.exe')
> ```

You definitely won't have a `geckodriver.exe` at that location on Heroku. Dynos don't run Windows, and Heroku doesn't provide graphical browsers by default.

You'll have to add an appropriate buildpack, e.g.

- The [Heroku-maintained Google Chrome buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) or
- This [Firefox buildpack from the community](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/ivandeex/heroku-buildpack-firefox)

and modify your code so you aren't hard-coding a path to a specific executable. If the executable is on your `PATH` you should just be able to do something like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: Is it possible to use driver without PATH requirements.  Ideally, I would like to be able to control default browser of end-user's system. Still trying to figure that part out.

Comment: I changed my code per your recommendations. Everything works locally but still issues when deployed. OP has been updated

Comment: @goryef, sorry, I missed this response earlier. If you use the Google Chrome buildpack it looks like you also need the [separate Chromedriver buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver).