# I'm trying to upload the bot to heroku server, I get this error:

Tags: python, heroku

I can't solve this problem, could it be my mistake?

Errors:

[image]

My files:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows a file that appears to be called `parser_twitter`, but Windows recognizes it as a Python file. Similarly, `chromedriver` doesn't have a visible extension, but Windows recognizes it as an executable.

This suggests that Windows Explorer [is hiding known file extensions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/common-file-name-extensions-in-windows-da4a4430-8e76-89c5-59f7-1cdbbc75cb01). Those files are almost certainly *really* named `parser_twitter.py` and `chromedriver.exe`.

But your `requirements.txt` and `runtime.txt` file extensions are visible. That would mean they are *actually* called `requirements.txt.txt` and `runtime.txt.txt`.

I suggest turning off that "feature" so you can see what your files are actually called:

> In File Explorer under **View**, in the **Show/hide** group, select the **File name extensions** check box.

Rename those files to remove the duplicate file extensions, commit, and redeploy.

---

Aside: If you have committed the `chromedriver.exe` file you're going to find that it doesn't work on Heroku. See [Selenium web driver can't open browser on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57380046/354577), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Python buildpack on your app? You can try checking it on the site or just run `$ heroku buildpacks -app <your app name>` if its not in there add it by running `$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python -a <your app name>`

Comment: Setting buildpacks manually isn't normally required for single-language applications.